# JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter:

Tags: python, json

I'm running following python code to read data from multiple JSON file using python on data bricks

```
mypath='***'
infiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

file_list=infiles
filename = file_list[0]
file_list = file_list[1:]
print(filename)

with open('***/' + filename) as json_file:
    data_json = json.load(json_file)
for filename in file_list:
   print(filename)
   with open('***' + filename) as json_file:
      add_json = json.load(json_file)
   data_json = json.loads('[' + json.dumps(data_json)[1:-1] + ',' + json.dumps(add_json)[1:-1] + ']')
```

I'm getting following error message in json.loads command

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter:
```

But while I'm reading individual file using below code

```
mypath='***'
infiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
file_list=infiles
for filename in file_list:
   print(filename)
   with open('***' + filename) as json_file:
      add_json = json.load(json_file)
```

Then my code is running fine. Can you let me know what wrong I'm doing in json.dumps?

Comment: datacentric error -you do not show the data. use `with open("f.txt","w") as f:` to `f.write('[' + json.dumps(data_json)[1:-1] + ',' + json.dumps(add_json)[1:-1] + ']')`  and put the thing through a json validator and fix the error you create

Comment: Why are you doing `dumps` only to `loads` - if the data has already been `loads` to a list, simply concatenate the lists. But to debug it rather than asking here where we can’t see your data, simply print the string you are trying to `loads` Or write it to file and load into an editor.

Comment: Sorry, Patrick, I didn't get . Are you meaning following steps 1. Instead of open I will use write,2.put `f` through json validator to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi bany, sorry I'm new to python. In some code repo I saw dumps for loading multiple JSON files so I used that. Can you suggest me how to load multiple JSON file together using loads?